# Symfony3: OAuth2 Token after form login with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, symfony

i'm using FOSUserBundle for a traditional login form on a Symfony3 project. Few days ago i've also configured FOSRestBundle and FOSOAuthServerBundle so i can serve Rest APIs with OAuth2 authentication. Now i have two ways to make login:
- Traditional web login with FOSUserBundle
- OAuth2 login (used with mobile apps)

I wonder what's the best practice to obtain an OAuth2 token after the traditional login. Should i make an automatic OAuth2 login after the traditional one to obtain a token and store it in user's session? Or is there a better way to accomplish it?

Another question could be: should i use this approach or is my logic wrong? Maybe i should redirect the web form directly to the oauth2 login to obtain an access token directly?